# boot2docker on windows - Can't share folders

Tags: windows, docker, samba

I'm running [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) v1.2.0 on windows 7 and have followed the instructions for [folder sharing](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing).

I get messages in the docker console indicating that the samba server is starting, and when I do `docker logs samba-server` I get some output that looks like it's working:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker logs samba-server
Setting up samba cfg --start my-data1 /data
add /data
Starting Samba daemons: nmbd smbd.
watching /var/log/samba/*
==> /var/log/samba/cores <==

==> /var/log/samba/log.nmbd <==
[2014/08/30 20:24:28,  0] nmbd/nmbd.c:861(main)
  nmbd version 3.6.6 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011

==> /var/log/samba/log.smbd <==
[2014/08/30 20:24:28,  0] smbd/server.c:1053(main)
  smbd version 3.6.6 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
tail: error reading `/var/log/samba/cores': Is a directory
tail: /var/log/samba/cores: cannot follow end of this type of file; giving up on
 this name
[2014/08/30 20:24:28.448867,  0] printing/print_cups.c:110(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2014/08/30 20:24:28.449807,  0] printing/print_cups.c:487(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL

==> /var/log/samba/log.nmbd <==
[2014/08/30 20:24:51,  0] nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)

  *****

  Samba name server 45DFC66E7CED is now a local master browser for workgroup WOR
KGROUP on subnet 172.17.0.10

  *****
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

But when I go to Windows Explorer and type in `\\192.168.59.103\data` I get nothing but an error message:

[image]

I've tried just about everything suggested here: [Cannot connect to a shared network drive](https://superuser.com/questions/384030/cannot-connect-to-a-shared-network-drive) and most of the suggestions here: [network error 0x80070035 the network path was not found](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-error-0x80070035-the-network-path-was-not/a0033200-5d96-40a7-abc6-e243921206bd)

I've also tried the suggestions at https://github.com/SvenDowideit/dockerfiles/issues/1 with no change.

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507953/boot2docker-mount-windows-share) that installing `cifs-utils` using `tce-load` worked, but I'm not sure how to do that. When I run `tce-load -wi cifs-utils` at the boot2docker prompt, I get `wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`. I can install this ok: `tce-load -wi sshfs-fuse` though I'm not sure what to do next. When I `ping google.com` I get responses, so I think my internet connection through boot2docker is ok.

How to make folder sharing work between boot2docker and the windows 7 host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got file sharing working by deleting all the boot2docker and virtualbox dot files and folders, uninstalling boot2docker and virtualbox, and then regressing through previous versions of virtualbox until I got to 4.3.12 and then folder sharing worked exactly as described.

**UPDATE**

Now I'm using boot2docker [v1.3.1](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/releases/) and it works fine with the version of VirtualBox that is bundled with the installer, no need to revert to an older version, and the `-v` flag works for folder sharing on windows, just as it does on Linux/OSX. So to share folders I'm doing this:

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 -v /c/Users/foobar:/home/rstudio/foobar rocker/rstudio
```

In this case, `/c/Users/foobar` corresponds to an existing folder on my computer at `C:/Users/foobar`, and `foobar` can be anything. With this method I can read and write files both ways between Windows and [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/products/RStudio/) and I don't need to connect to a special IP address like the samba method does in the official docs

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the file you have posted, your docker machine is running at 172.17.0.10, not 192.168.59.103. When you boot up the image, add the --bip=192.168.59.103/24 or whatever subnet you wish to use to it, to attach that specific IP. Otherwise, it just NATS

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, do you mean to try `boot2docker ssh --bip=192.168.59.103/24`? Because that makes no difference. I am running `boot2docker ip` in another terminal each time I test this, and ever time it's 192.168.59.103, as [suggested by the instructions](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing). Putting `172.17.0.10` in the explorer bar also does nothing.